# Not able launch Android Instant App with Google-Play-Services (Maps basically)

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-instant-apps

The purpose of posting images is to spot the errors easily as it is not the normal manifest file.

I'm trying to display Google Maps inside an `instant app` application. Now the application **gets installed successfully** (and runs smoothly) if I try to run it **via** `app` module i.e. normal install (which means I have included all the necessary `gradle` dependencies and API key) but if I try to run it as an `instant app` (not `instant run`) I'm facing this error:

[image: this]

and it takes me to debug/xml file:

[image]

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: First, please post text, not images of text. Second, the stacktrace tells you the resource @integer/google_play_services_version does not exist. So there's your problem.

Comment: hah! Like I haven't checked it. It is a debug/xml file which means it created dynamically and I can't edit it. And read the problem carefully, it is working fine if I run the application normally.

Comment: who so ever downvoted this question: WHY?

Comment: Unclear of what I'm asking? Are you even aware of Android instant apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem occurs when you include the `google-play-services` dependency in a non-base feature module. The underlying issue is that although the

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

element is added to the base feature's `AndroidManifest.xml`, the referenced id (`@integer/google_play_services_version`) is not available since the dependency is defined, and scoped, in another feature module.

The easiest, and most maintainable, workaround is to add the `google-play-services` dependency to the base feature module. Everything included in the base is available to non-base features, but as this error shows the opposite is not true.

Comment: I did, still didn't work. Were you successfully able to do it?

Comment: Dennis - dscannell's suggestion should work (moving com.google.android.gms:play-services... dep from feature to base build.gradle file). Can you post your build.gradle files which aren't working?